# How to reverse the numbers when using the shell command "select"?

Tags: bash, shell

v.sh

```
select f in "$@" ; do
    echo $f
done
```

`v.sh a b c` Result below:

```
1) a
2) b
3) c
#?
```

But I want this below and I can select the options.

```
3) a
2) b
1) c
#?
```

How to solve it in a easy way? Thx in advance.

Comment: Didn't quite get it, what do you mean by select the options?

Comment: @Karan Shah: That means the default function of the "select".

Comment: @BigShield : I don't think it's possible with using select

Comment: One possibility would be to change [this script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203327/74329).

Comment: @Inian I agree with you.

Comment: @Cyrus Thx for your script. I can learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, you cannot modify `select`'s numbering, but you can create a custom `select` implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Custom `select` implementation that prints the menu items
# passed as arguments with reverse numbering, prompts for a selection,
# and outputs the selected item.
customSelect() {

  local item i=0 numItems=$# 

  # Print menu items with reverse numbering.
  for item; do
    printf '%s\n' "$((numItems - i++))) $item"
  done >&2 # Print to stderr, as `select` does.

  # Prompt the user for the index of the desired item.
  while :; do
    printf %s "${PS3-#? }" >&2 # Print the prompt string to stderr, as `select` does.
    read -r index
    # Make sure that a valid index was entered.
    (( index >= 1 && index <= numItems )) || { echo "Invalid selection." >&2; continue; }
    break
  done

  # Determine selected item by index entered and print it to stdout.
  printf %s "${@: numItems - index + 1 : 1}"

}

# Present the custom menu and prompt for a selection.
selectedItem=$(customSelect "$@")

# Process the selected item.
case $selectedItem in
  # YOUR HANDLERS HERE.
  *) # Sample handler
    echo "Selected item: [$selectedItem]"
    ;;
esac
```

---

<sup>Tip of the hat to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for his help.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can not reverse the automatic numbering of `select` but you can reverse the arguments which does the same job (logically).

This one-liner test works ok in my bash and selections made correspond to the correct reversed item:

```
$: function test { select f in $(echo $@|rev) ;do echo $f;done;};test a b c
1) c
2) b
3) a
#? 1
c
#? 2
b
#? 3
a
```

PS: In your script you don't need the function. You just apply

```
select f in $(echo $@|rev) ;do
    echo $f
done
```

**Update**
As noted in comments, the use of `rev` for reverting the args is valid for single character args like the OP example (`a b c`).
If an argument consists of more chars (i.e `cd`) then `rev` will revert this arg also (i.e to `dc`).

In this case is more safe to store args in an array in reverse order , and then select will refer to this reverted array like this:

```
$: function test { local arr;for ((i=${#@};i>0;i--));do \ 
arr+=("${@:$i:1}");done;select f in "${arr[@]}";do echo "$f";done;};test a b cd
1) cd
2) b
3) a
#? 1
cd
```

Moreover, care must be taken for using `*` as an argument . It must be quoted (i.e `'*'`) otherwise bash will expand it to the contents of the current working directory. This limitation applies even in OPs very first example.

Comment: Your solution works with the sample menu items, but is generally limited to single-character menu items, and even then would break with a menu item named `*`.
If you don't want to generalize your solution, I think it would help others if you stated these limitations in your answer.

Comment: Using `unset` destroys what might already be a global variable. Use `local arr` instead to make a local variable that doesn't interfere with any preexisting globals.

Comment: Thanks for updating. While `${#@}` inexplicably works, the correct form is `$#`. Can I suggest you _only_ show your _updated_ solution in your answer? The original one is so limited and has so many pitfalls (use of an unquoted command substitution and unquoted `$@` is a bad habit to promote). Speaking of: I suggest you simply use `$` to represent the prompt in your examples. Not only is `root@debian` a distraction, it too promotes a bad habit: running as the root user. Finally, no more need for `unset`, given that `local` makes `arr` go out of scope automatically.

Comment: Also: With the updated solution, there is _no_ problem with globbing, as long as you pass the menu items themselves quoted on _invocation_ - that's the right and only way to do it; e.g., `test a b cd 'item 4' '*'`. Perhaps your comment only related to the original solution, but that's not obvious from its placement (and, again, I suggest showing only the updated solution).